# Is there any implication of a large log-likelihood value?

Tags: maximum-likelihood, ordered-logit, multinomial-logit, mlogit, clogit

I have estimated a discrete choice model using the MLE procedure and got a very large log-likelihood value (log-likelihood: -236018.2). Is there any implication to the result?

[edit]
I have 4300 observations about household consumption. I have used multiple discrete continuous extreme value (MDCEV) method. I have estimated MDCEV model with outside good for 9 choice options (one is outside good that is one choice is always consumed).
I have used R for the estimation using the [code](http://www.mobilityanalytics.org/r-codes-for-travel-modeling.html). I have tried gamma and alpha profile but got similar Log-Likelihood value.

Comment: That's a low log-likelihood; the model considers it unlikely. High would be close to zero.

Comment: Could you give more details about your dataset? 236,000 points of log-likelihood seems a bit crazy, unless you have a lot of observations (choices) in your database. How did you obtain this large value? (Which software, model specification, etc). In the past I have estimated "basic" discrete choice models on ~15,000 observations and obtained a log-lik below 30,000 points.

Comment: I have estimated MDCEV model with outside goods using R. it has 4300 household survey data and 9 expenditure categories are as the dependent variable.

Comment: First, this is not an answer. Second, it is wrong as it assumes that you can meaningfully interpret log-likelihood. Please refer to the answer by Jake Westfall: there is no such a thing as "objectively" large or small LL, it depends on your model, data and the sample size, there is nothing "crazy" in this value.

Comment: @Tim. I agree, my comment was simply based on my experience of estimating discrete choice models on dataset of different sizes. In practice, it seems unlikely to obtain a log-lik value of 200,000+ points when the dependent variable is binary and number of observations limited. I am not saying that is impossible, but very unlikely and I would take it as an indication of potential mistake in model coding/specification. However, this case is different as the DV appears to be ordinal with 9 categories.

Answer (score 7):

No. The log-likelihood value depends on the scale of the response variable and the size of the dataset. It cannot be meaningfully interpreted in an absolute way.

Comment: How does it depend on the scale of the response variable?

Comment: @BenOgorek Because the scale of the response variable alters the density values upon which the log-likelihood is based (since densities must integrate to 1). So, all else equal, increasing the scale of the response variable causes the densities to take on smaller values, causing the total log-likelihood to be lower. You can try it out on some toy data.

Comment: Thanks. Yeah I momentarily forgot about the -log sigma in every normal log likelihood.

Comment: @Tim That's in my answer ("the size of the dataset")

Comment: Missed it sorry (I already +1d)